# ssh login and run source command but not work

Tags: bash, ssh

everyone:

I have a bash script named work.sh doing some background taska on my server machine.
**I can run it on the server successfully.**
But now, I want to trigger this bash script on my client machine using ssh.

so I use command like this:

```
ssh server "cd ~/working_dir && source work.sh"
```

But in fact the background tasks were not started successfully. How can I find the problem and fix this?

edit:

the script work.sh on the server looks like this:

```
commandA args 1>log.txt 2>err.txt &
echo "commandA start"
```

after I run

```
ssh server "cd ~/working_dir && source work.sh"
```

on the client machine, I got output:

```
commandA start
```

But when I login on the server and check the commandA. I can't find it running on the server machine.

Thanks!!

Comment: log the errors. Are the background tasks required to have root access?

Comment: Go ahead and check `~/working_dir/log.txt` and `~/working_dir/err.txt` on the remote server...

Comment: @heemayl nothing there. Actually even if i delete the log.txt and err.txt, they can not be generated by the ssh command. But I can run the same bash script successfully on the server machine.

Comment: You either want to source the script or run it. It sounds like you want to run it, so why do you source it?

Comment: @Jakuje I want to use source command to run the script. is there a problem with that? I can run the script with " source work.sh " successfully on the server.

Comment: Did you try to replace the ~ with the full path of the directory?